# Why can I pass the wrong interface to a function without compiler errors?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, parameters, interface, arguments

Curious if I've messed up some Visual Studo settings that should be flagging this, or if I'm misunderstanding something entirely.

I have a funcion A which has 2 very basic interfaces as parameters:

1. oConfiguration as IConfiguration
2. oEventLogHandler as IEventLogHandler

Function B has a single parameter:

1. oEventLogHandler as IEventLogHandler

Function A calls Function B, passing oConfiguration as an argument. I don't seem to get any compiler errors or warnings in Visual Studio but of course I get the runtime error:

**Unable to cast object of type 'ConfigurationImplementationA' to type 'IEventLogHandler'.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

It's off by default to support legacy VB6 code.  Otherwise, it's just pain and suffering to leave it off, so don't.

See also : [What do Option Strict and Option Explicit do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2454552/327083)